# Access the name of the current fixture and test at runtime

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

For usage as in

```
test(testName, async (t) => {
  const ua = await getUA()

  await t.takeScreenshot(
    fixtureName +
      "/" +
      testName +
      "/" +
      identifyUserAgent(ua) +
      "/" +
      "scsh_1.png",
  )
...
```

As of testcafe@0.21.1 my workaround is

```
const fixtureName = "Index_Page_Test"

fixture(fixtureName).page(...)

...

const testName = "dom_has_critical_elements"

test(testName, async (t) => {
...
```

but would prefer to have it available on t. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At preset, `t` does not contain the test and fixtures names. For your purpose (build path for `takeScreenshot` action) you can use the [custom screenshot pattern](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-p---screenshot-path-pattern) feature.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. I was aware of the custom screenshot pattern feature. But this is not exposed either at runtime. The intended goal of above usage is to implement a image diff of a current screenshot against an expected screenshot. So i must take control of the current screenshot file location to read it back. As an aside, i would prefer to opt to get the screenshot bytes in a  Buffer. Which would allow me to be more flexible.

Answer (score 5):

According to https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2826, you can use

- `t.testRun.test.name` to obtain the current test's name, and
- `t.testRun.test.testFile.currentFixture.name` to obtain the current fixture's name.

Tried it myself, and it works. It seems to be a non-documented feature, though.

Comment: For anyone using TypeScript, the following workaround is available https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2826#issuecomment-524377039

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there is no way to get testname from the test or fixture, please refer to enhancement request logged in TestCafe:

https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2823 (No way to get current testname using c.ctx or c.fixtureCtx? #2823)

https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2826 (Allow to use test and fixture names inside hooks and test bodies)